# Excel VBA loop through worksheek, insert a new row when there are multiple values for data, keeping the rest of the information the same

Tags: excel, vba, insert, rows

I currently have a large set of information, its size varies. The last piece of data may span 1 column, 0 columns, or many columns.

I need a row for each individual piece of data, and for all of the data to be in the same column.

[image: This image shows an example of the original data and expected outcome]

I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
R=11
For each cell in Range(Range("C2"), 
Range("C2").End(xlDown))
i=0
Do
    Cells(R,1).value=cell.offset(0, -2).value
    Cells(R,2).value=cell.offset(0, -1).value
    Cells(R,2).value=cell.offset(0, i).value
    R=R+1
     i=i+1
Loop until cell.offset(0,i).value=""
Next
```

Comment: Nice. Do you think @Derek would want some comments to understand what's going on? If you don't know about row/column notation or ranges, there's a lot going on. ;)

Comment: R=11     'the first row to paste the data
For each cell in Range(Range("C2"), 
Range("C2").End(xlDown))    'cells C2 to last cell down
i=0
Do
    Cells(R,1).value=cell.offset(0, -2).value   'Test Data
    Cells(R,2).value=cell.offset(0, -1).value   'Time Data
    Cells(R,2).value=cell.offset(0, i).value      'Data 
    R=R+1     'add 1 row down if have more data 
     i=i+1       'i refer Data value to the right
Loop until cell.offset(0,i).value=""
Next

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Can you please edit this into your answer? That way you can format and align your extra information neatly.

Answer (score 0):

```
R=11 'the first row to paste the data 
For each cell in _
     Range(Range("C2"),Range("C2").End(xlDown))
      'cells C2 to last cell down
i=0 
Do 
    Cells(R,1).value=cell.offset(0, -2).value 'Test Data 
    Cells(R,2).value=cell.offset(0, -1).value 'Time Data 
    Cells(R,2).value=cell.offset(0, i).value 'Data
    R=R+1    'add 1 row down if have more data
    i=i+1      'i refer Data value to the right 
 Loop until cell.offset(0,i).value="" 
 Next
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you additionally want to get rid of the old data and only see the newly formatted data here my adjustemnt to the code from Lee Li Fong

```
`Sub Formating ()

'Counts how many rows of data you want to formate
With ActiveSheet
lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

R = lastRow + 1 'the first row to paste the data
For Each cell In _
     Range(Range("E3"), Range("E3").End(xlDown))
      'cells E3 to last cell down
i = 0
Do
    Cells(R,1).value=cell.offset(0, -2).value 'Test Data 
    Cells(R,2).value=cell.offset(0, -1).value 'Time Data
    Cells(R, 5).Value = cell.Offset(0, i).Value 'Data
    R = R + 1 'add 1 row down if have more data
    i = i + 1  'i refer Data value to the right
 Loop Until cell.Offset(0, i).Value = ""
 Next


Worksheets("Data").Range("3:" & lastRow).EntireRow.Delete 'deletes the old unformated data

End Sub   `
```